# How to test a React component that update over time with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this React Component

```
export class Timer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {i : props.i};
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.decrementCounter();
}

decrementCounter(){
    if(this.state.i < 1){
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({i : this.state.i - 1})
        this.decrementCounter()}, 1000);
}

render(){
    return <span>{this.state.i}</span>
}}
```

And I want to express a test like this

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
it('should decrement timer ', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Timer i={10} />);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe("10");
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe("9");
});
```

currently the first expect pass but the second fails

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
      "9"
    Received:
      "10"
```

How can I properly test this component ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Full Rendering API, mount(...)](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)

> Full DOM rendering is ideal for use cases where you have components
>   that may interact with DOM APIs, or **may require the full lifecycle in
>   order to fully test the component** (i.e., **componentDidMount** etc.)

You can use `mount()` instead of `shallow()` like

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, /* shallow */ } from 'enzyme';
import Timer from './index';

describe('Timer', () => {
    it('should decrement timer ', () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();

        const wrapper = mount(<Timer i={10} />);
        expect(wrapper.text()).toBe("10");
        jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
        expect(wrapper.text()).toBe("9");

        jest.useRealTimers();
    });
});
```

Or you can pass additional object to `shallow` to instrument it to run lifecycle methods

- [see ShallowWrapper.js sourcode](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/817a76d88a35f3bd89a6c36d8bbb9d018ecc5ccb/src/ShallowWrapper.js#L72)
- [see shallow() docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/v2.8.2/docs/api/shallow.md#arguments)

> options.disableLifecycleMethods: (Boolean [optional]): If set to true,
>   componentDidMount is not called on the component, and
>   componentDidUpdate is not called after setProps and setContext.

```
const options = {
  lifecycleExperimental: true,
  disableLifecycleMethods: false 
};

const wrapper = shallow(<Timer i={10} />, options);
```

I tested it. It works.

```
hinok:~/workspace $ npm test

> c9@0.0.0 test /home/ubuntu/workspace
> jest

 PASS  ./index.spec.js (7.302s)
  Timer
    ✓ should decrement timer  (28ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.162s
Ran all test suites.
```