# Access state of component using Jest + Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, enzyme

I have a container class LoadingIndicator connected using redux.

I am trying to test if the showIndicator is set to true after the timer is run using Enzyme and Jest. But I am unable to get access to the state and I get error : **Cannot read property 'showIndicator' of null**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class LoadingIndicator extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.timeoutID = null;
  this.state = {
    showIndicator: false,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.ensureTimer(this.props);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.destroyTimer();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  if (props.loading !== this.props.loading || props.error !== this.props.error) {
    this.ensureTimer(props);
  }
}

ensureTimer(props) {
  if (props.loading && !props.error) {
    if (!this.timeoutID) {
      this.timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
        this.timeoutID = null;
        this.setState({ showIndicator: true });
      }, props.timeoutPeriod);
    }
  } else {
    this.destroyTimer();
  }
}

destroyTimer() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeoutID);
  this.timeoutID = null;
  this.setState({ showIndicator: false });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className={`${this.state.showIndicator ? 'loading-show' : 'loading-hidden'}`}>
      <LoadingIndicatorComponent>
        Loading...
      </LoadingIndicatorComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loading: isLoading(state),
  error: hasError(state),
});

// timeoutPeriod of 1000 is for showing loading indicator after 1000ms
LoadingIndicator.defaultProps = {
  timeoutPeriod: 1000,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoadingIndicator);
```

My test file is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import i18nUtils from '../../i18n';

import ConnectedLoadingIndicator, { LoadingIndicator } from './loadingIndicator';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('Connected loading container component', () => {

  const initialState = {
    app: {
      loading: true,
      error: false
    },
  };

  const mockStore = configureStore();
  let store;
  let container;
  let component;
  let spyMount;

  const intlConfig = i18nUtils.getIntlConfig();

  beforeAll(()=> {
    spyMount = jest.spyOn(ConnectedLoadingIndicator.prototype, 
                          'componentDidMount');
    store = mockStore(initialState);
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider {...intlConfig}>
          <ConnectedLoadingIndicator />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
    container = wrapper.find(ConnectedLoadingIndicator);
    component = container.find(LoadingIndicator);
  });


  it('checks componentDidMount is called', () => {
    expect(spyMount).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('checks state showIndicator is called', () => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    console.log(wrapper.state().showIndicator);
  });

});
```

But when I do console.log(component); I get the below information in terminal :

```
ReactWrapper {
       component: null,
       root:
        ReactWrapper {
          component:

           WrapperComponent {
             props: [Object],
             context: {},
             refs: {},
             updater: [Object],
             state: [Object],
             _reactInternalInstance: [Object] },
          root: [Circular],
          node:
           Provider {
             props: [Object],
             context: {},
             refs: {},
             updater: [Object],
             store: [Object],
             _reactInternalInstance: [Object],
             state: null },
          nodes: [ [Object] ],
          length: 1,
          options: {},
          complexSelector:
           ComplexSelector {
             buildPredicate: [Function: buildInstPredicate],
             findWhereUnwrapped: [Function: findWhereUnwrapped],
             childrenOfNode: [Function: childrenOfInst] } },
node:
        LoadingIndicator {
          props:
           { loading: true,
             error: false,
             dispatch: [Function: dispatch],
             timeoutPeriod: 1000 },
          context: {},
          refs: {},
          updater:
           { isMounted: [Function: isMounted],
             enqueueCallback: [Function: enqueueCallback],
             enqueueCallbackInternal: [Function: enqueueCallbackInternal],
             enqueueForceUpdate: [Function: enqueueForceUpdate],
             enqueueReplaceState: [Function: enqueueReplaceState],

             enqueueSetState: [Function: enqueueSetState],
             enqueueElementInternal: [Function: enqueueElementInternal],
             validateCallback: [Function: validateCallback] },
          timeoutID: null,
          state: { showIndicator: true },
          _reactInternalInstance:
           ReactCompositeComponentWrapper {
             _currentElement: [Object],
             _rootNodeID: 0,
             _compositeType: 0,
             _instance: [Circular],
             _hostParent: null,
             _hostContainerInfo: [Object],
             _updateBatchNumber: null,
             _pendingElement: null,
             _pendingStateQueue: null,
             _pendingReplaceState: false,
             _pendingForceUpdate: false,
             _renderedNodeType: 0,
             _renderedComponent: [Object],
             _context: [Object],
             _mountOrder: 6,
             _topLevelWrapper: null,
             _pendingCallbacks: null,
             _calledComponentWillUnmount: false,
             _warnedAboutRefsInRender: false,
             _mountIndex: 0,
             _mountImage: null,
             _debugID: 13 } },
       nodes:
        [ LoadingIndicator {
            props: [Object],
            context: {},
            refs: {},
            updater: [Object],
            timeoutID: null,
            state: [Object],
            _reactInternalInstance: [Object] } ],
       length: 1,
       options: {},
       complexSelector:
        ComplexSelector {
          buildPredicate: [Function: buildInstPredicate],
          findWhereUnwrapped: [Function: findWhereUnwrapped],
          childrenOfNode: [Function: childrenOfInst] } }
```

Comment: shallow() doesn't run lifecycle methods by default, longer explanation about lifecycle methods + enzyme is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569361/how-to-test-a-react-component-that-update-over-time-with-jest-and-enzyme/43570453#43570453

Comment: @hinok: How can I access the showIndicator of state through wrapper or component here?

Comment: `.instance()`, https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.md, `.state()` - https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/state.md methods can be used only on root wrappers. You can try access states by internal structure like `wrapper.find('LoadingIndicator').nodes[0].state` but it's not the recommended way to do it and you have to check manually which node you want to choose. To avoid this, you should test component's state in isolation, more on this: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/361

Comment: @hinok: Thanks :)